# ActiveAdmin eager loading not working for model named "Search" (name collision)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I've been using ActiveAdmin eager loading in almost all my models. For instance, this works great for my Coach model:

app/admin/coaches.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Coach do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      Coach.includes(:addresses, :user, :sport, {:user => :user_metric})
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I recently tried this same thing with my Search model (which I use to record searches users have done):

app/admin/searches.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Search do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      Search.includes(:sport)
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error when I try to visit /admin/searches

```
NoMethodError in Admin::SearchesController#index

undefined method `includes' for
ActiveAdmin::ResourceController::Collection::Search:Module

app/admin/searches.rb:5:in `scoped_collection'
```

I believe what may be happening here is the constant `Search` I'm using in my eager loading is referring to some internal ActiveAdmin module rather than my ActiveRecord model. Is there a way to prevent this name collision? Maybe ActiveRecord::Search (or something like that)? Or possibly something else entirely is going on here?

The constant `Search` works everywhere else on the site, and the ActiveAdmin searches page worked fine before trying to implement eager loading.

Comment: try ::Search instead of Search

Answer (score 1):

As @Fivell recommended, try `::Search` instead of `Search`.
It looks like your reference to `Search` in `app/admin/searches.rb:5` is actually referencing `ActiveAdmin::ResourceController::Collection::Search`.

If that doesn't solve the issue, and it might not, I recommend renaming your `Search` class to something else, as name collisions tend to crop up weird bugs...

Good luck!